# como hacer un push en un estado con react?

Tags: reactjs

Buenas tardes amigos una pregunta: Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer un push en un estado en react ?
cómo haria un push para lograr algo asi:  itemseleted:[123, 455,333] ?

```
 this.state = {
  itemseleted:[]
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar setState, para no mutar tu estado debes usarlo de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
this.setState(state => [...state, number])
```

Donde `number` es el numero que quieres agregar al final del arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca actualices un estado de react directamente, usa `setState`, no se exactamente cual es la estructura de tu código, pero probablemente ocupes hacer algo así:

```
this.setState= {
  state:{
      itemseleted:[123, 455,333]
    }
};
```

Te recomiendo leer [esta documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Si lo que quieres hacer es literalmente utilizar el método push del array que ya tienes en tu estado, entonces algo cómo:

```
this.setState= {
  state:{
      itemseleted: this.state.itemseleted.push(333)
    }
};
```